# Matching range of timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble doing this in pandas

DF1 (my left join):

```
Name |     TimeStart        | TimeEnd               | Values   | Order
John   12/24/2014 08:10:32    12/24/2014 08:14:21        2        1
John   12/24/2014 08:15:03    12/24/2014 08:22:49        2        2
```

DF2

```
Name |     TimeStart        | TimeEnd               | Values
John   12/24/2014 08:12:57    12/24/2014 08:13:31        8
```

TimeStart in DF2 is ALWAYS greater than the TimeStart in DF1 (this typically happens during the interaction). And for it to match, it would have to be less than the next row of data for that individual.

Here is my thought process. Shift the row to columns to see if they match. Then compare the DF2 TimeStart to be > than the initial TimeStart on DF1 but less than the next row TimeStart (same Name).

```
df1.sort(['Name', 'TimeStart'], ascending=[1, 1], inplace = True)
df1['Name_R'] = df1['Name'].shift(-1)
df1['Matching Row'] = np.where((df1['Name_R'] == df1['Name']), 1, 0)
df1['Next Timestamp'] = np.where(df1['Matching Row'] == 1, df1['TimeStart'].shift(-1), np.datetime64('nat'))
df1['test'] = np.where(df2['TimeStart'] > df1['TimeStart'] < df1['Next Timestamp'], 1, 0)
```

Edit -  is it possible to do this with a asof command? The only trick is that the Name has to match, then we look for the closest timestamp for TimeStart on each file/dataframe.

Comment: What is your desired output? Can we assume the combination of Name and TimeStart will always be unique?

Comment: Yes,  Name+TimeStart is unique. I want to match the DF2 file with the DF1. Part of the total time on DF1 (TimeEnd  -  TimeStart)  is the time on DF2. It is unknown which rows in DF1 have corresponding DF2 data. I want to get the total amount of time DF2 is impacting DF1 by joining these files together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ["asof join" in pandas 0.19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-asof-merge). For your example, just ignore the starting time and join by the most recent ending time.

```
pd.merge_asof(DF1, DF2, on='TimeEnd')
```

Comment: Nice, I will have to test that out. I never fully resolved this issue. My workaround was to only find rows where the Person and the Customer only had one interaction on a certain date. If they had multiple interactions, I would not attempt to join the data. This might increase my 'match' rate

Comment: Yeah, there have been many workarounds to this problem for a long time. The version of pandas released *today* finally solves this.

Comment: Thanks for responding so I was alerted. Hah, did you just google for this and respond to relevant questions? It's been a while since I made this post.